# is it possible to have alphanumeric sequence generator in sql

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I need to write a SQL query to print the following aphanumberic sequence in SQL

0001,
0002, 
... ,
0009,
000A, 
... ,
000Z, 
... ,
0010,
0011, 
... ,
001A,
... and so on till... ,
ZZZZ

please note: all characters are UPPERCASE.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could create a function like this:

```
create function to_base_36 (n integer) return varchar2
is
  q integer;
  r varchar2(100);
begin
  q := n;
  while q >= 36 loop
     r := chr(mod(q,36)+case when mod(q,36) < 10 then 48 else 55 end) || r;
     q := floor(q/36);
  end loop;
  r := chr(mod(q,36)+case when mod(q,36) < 10 then 48 else 55 end) || r;
  return lpad(r,4,'0');
end;
```

and then use it like this:

```
select rownum, to_base_36(rownum)
from dual
connect by level < 36*36*36*36;
```

Or, without creating a function:

```
with digits as
( select n, chr(mod(n,36)+case when mod(n,36) < 10 then 48 else 55 end) d
  from (Select rownum-1 as n from dual connect by level < 37)
)
select d1.n*36*36*36 + d2.n*36*36 + d3.n*36 + d4.n, d1.d||d2.d||d3.d||d4.d
from digits d1, digits d2, digits d3, digits d4
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this function:

```
create or replace FUNCTION SEQGEN(vinp in varchar2, iSeq in INTEGER) 
RETURN VARCHAR2 is vResult VARCHAR2(32);
  iBas INTEGER; iRem INTEGER; iQuo INTEGER; lLen CONSTANT INTEGER := 2;
BEGIN
  iBas := length(vInp);
  iQuo := iSeq;
  WHILE iQuo > 0 LOOP
    iRem := iQuo mod iBas;
    --dbms_output.put_line('Now we divide ' || lpad(iQuo,lLen,'0') || ' by ' || lpad(iBas,lLen,'0') || ', yielding a quotient of ' || lpad( TRUNC(iQuo / iBas) ,lLen,'0') || ' and a remainder of ' || lpad(iRem,lLen,'0') || ' giving the char: ' || substr(vInp, iRem, 1));
    iQuo := TRUNC(iQuo / iBas);
    If iRem < 1 Then iRem := iBas; iQuo := iQuo - 1; End If;
    vResult := substr(vInp, iRem, 1) || vResult;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN vResult;
END SEQGEN;
```

Try the function:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT seqgen('0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',rownum + 47989 --start value
) Output, level evt FROM dual CONNECT BY level < 1679618)  --stop value
WHERE mod(evt,50000) = 0 OR output in ('0001','0002','0009','000A','000Z',
                                       '0010','0011','001A','ZZZZ')
```

Note that if you change the string you must also change the start and stop value.

Read more about number systems here: [Number System Conversion - Explanation](http://courses.cs.vt.edu/~cs1104/number_conversion/convexp.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
-- To get 00000 to ZZZZZ next auto alphanumeric sequence using this function [Please verify before use]
-- This starts from 0-9 then A-Z and then increase next digit from 0-9 then A-Z
-- You need to pass the starting/Last sequence as value to get next sequence  
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION return_next_seq (curr_sequence VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
 retval VARCHAR2(4000) := NULL;
 retMaxval VARCHAR2(4000) := NULL;
 eval_digit CHAR(1) := NULL;
 original_sequence VARCHAR2(4000) := curr_sequence;
 curr1_sequence VARCHAR2(4000) := curr_sequence;
BEGIN
retval := original_sequence;
FOR j IN REVERSE 1..LENGTH(curr1_sequence) LOOP -- Using reverse to know
-- the exact digit position
eval_digit := SUBSTR(curr1_sequence, LENGTH(curr1_sequence));
--IF (ASCII(eval_digit) BETWEEN 49 AND 56) OR
--(ASCII(eval_digit) BETWEEN 97 AND 121) THEN
IF (ASCII(eval_digit) BETWEEN 48 AND 56) OR
(ASCII(eval_digit) BETWEEN 65 AND 89) THEN
eval_digit := CHR(ASCII(eval_digit) +1);
curr1_sequence := SUBSTR(curr1_sequence,1,LENGTH(curr1_sequence)-1);
retval := curr1_sequence || eval_digit || SUBSTR(original_sequence,
LENGTH(curr1_sequence || eval_digit)+1);
EXIT;
ELSE -- move to the next digit leaving the evaluated digit untouched.
    IF (ASCII(eval_digit) = 57) THEN
    eval_digit := CHR(ASCII(eval_digit) +8);
    curr1_sequence := SUBSTR(curr1_sequence,1,LENGTH(curr1_sequence)-1);
    retval := curr1_sequence || eval_digit || SUBSTR(original_sequence,
    LENGTH(curr1_sequence || eval_digit)+1);
    EXIT;
    END IF;
    IF (ASCII(eval_digit) = 90) THEN
        retMaxval :=  eval_digit;
        eval_digit := CHR(ASCII(eval_digit) -42);                                          
        curr1_sequence := SUBSTR(curr1_sequence,1,LENGTH(curr1_sequence)-1);
        FOR k IN REVERSE 1..LENGTH(curr1_sequence) LOOP
            IF (ASCII(SUBSTR(curr1_sequence,LENGTH(curr1_sequence))) BETWEEN 48 AND 56) OR (ASCII(SUBSTR(curr1_sequence,LENGTH(curr1_sequence))) BETWEEN 65 AND 89) THEN
            retval := SUBSTR(curr1_sequence,0,LENGTH(curr1_sequence)-1) || CHR(ASCII(SUBSTR(curr1_sequence,LENGTH(curr1_sequence)))+1) || eval_digit || SUBSTR(retval,
            LENGTH(curr1_sequence || eval_digit)+1);
            ELSE
                IF ASCII(SUBSTR(curr1_sequence,LENGTH(curr1_sequence))) = 57 THEN
                retval := SUBSTR(curr1_sequence,0,LENGTH(curr1_sequence)-1) || CHR(65) || eval_digit || SUBSTR(retval,
                LENGTH(curr1_sequence || eval_digit)+1);
                ELSE
                    IF ASCII(SUBSTR(curr1_sequence,LENGTH(curr1_sequence))) = 90 AND LENGTH(curr1_sequence)>1 THEN
                    retval := SUBSTR(curr1_sequence,0,LENGTH(curr1_sequence)-1) || CHR(48) || eval_digit || SUBSTR(retval,
                    LENGTH(curr1_sequence || eval_digit)+1);
                    curr1_sequence := SUBSTR(curr1_sequence,1,LENGTH(curr1_sequence)-1);
                    retMaxval := retMaxval||'Z';
                    ELSE
                    retMaxval := retMaxval||'Z'; 
                    EXIT;                   
                    END IF;
                END IF;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
            EXIT;
    ELSE
        curr1_sequence := SUBSTR(curr1_sequence,1,LENGTH(curr1_sequence)-1);
    END IF;
END IF;
END LOOP;
IF retval IS NULL OR (LENGTH(retval) = LENGTH(retMaxval)) THEN
RETURN 'MAX';
END IF;
RETURN retval;
END;

-- To verify, call this function like
SELECT return_next_seq('ZY9Z') FROM dual;
-- Any improvement suggestion is welcome!
--- Thanks!..Sanjiv
```